# PHP password_hash always contains hashkey

Tags: php, password-encryption, php-password-hash

I am trying to test the password_hash method for this purpose i have created the following function **hashPassword**:

```
function hashPassword($string) {
    $settings = array('cost' => 10, 'encryption_key' => 'thisIsMyEncryptionKey1234');
    return password_hash($string, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $settings);
}
```

Now if i test this with a random string like `"test"`

The result would be:

```
$2y$10$thisIsMyEncryptionKeyu5n3NNnKh3DjgJqgb5pE8YOLBclKrVWC
```

Or if i test it with `helloworld`:

```
$2y$10$thisIsMyEncryptionKeyuVw8QRVNw8HbEWHX2oQlArVtne2TzOpS
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? Or is it suppose to be like this?

Comment: Encryption key should be random generated

Comment: What? how do i validate if a users password is correct???

Comment: http://in3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php The answer by @Niels explains it

Comment: Passing `'encryption_key'` in the `$options` array does absolutely nothing. I think you mean `'salt'`.

Comment: Yes. There are only 2 supported options, salt and cost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should never provide the encryption key manually unless you have a very good reason to do so. [I'd recommend reading the docs on `password_hash` some more](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).

Proper usage just lets the system figure it all out on its own:

```
function hashPassword($password)
{
    return password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
}
```

PHP will then internally choose the best available algorithm and most fitting number of iterations for current hardware, and generate a safe and unique salt.

To validate the password, then use [`password_verify`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php), and check for required rehashes, for example in a `User` class:

```
class User
{
    ...

    public function verifyPassword($password)
    {
      if(!password_verify($password, $this->hash))
        return false;
      if(password_needs_rehash($this->hash, PASSWORD_DEFAULT))
        $this->setNewHashAndSaveToDB(password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
      return true;
    }
}
```

By using this construct, you ensure hashed passwords are always kept up to date and secure as hardware capacities progress, automatically when a user logs in.

The policy on what algorithm `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` chooses, and with which config, is as follows:

> Updates to supported algorithms by this function (or changes to the
>   default one) must follow the follwoing rules:
>
> - Any new algorithm must be in core for at least 1 full release of PHP    prior to becoming default. So if, for example, a new algorithm
>     is    added in 5.5.5, it would not be eligible for default until 5.7
>     (since
>     5.6 would be the first full release). But if a different algorithm was added in 5.6.0, it would also be eligible for default at 5.7.0.
> - The default should only change on a full release (5.6.0, 6.0.0, etc)    and not on a revision release. The only exception to this is
>     in an    emergency when a critical security flaw is found in the
>     current    default.

Comment: Say for instance you create a login system where you save the user password in the database? how would you then validate the password that the user inputs?

Comment: Added all that. [It's all in the docs though.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php)

Comment: doesent this make saving the hashed password in the database useless?

Comment: i dont get how the verifyPassword will verify anything without checking the database to match if the hash is the same as the one returned from the current password. which it will never be because the hashkey is random?

Comment: The 'hash key' is just a salt to ensure the resulting hash cannot be hacked with rainbow tables, and that the same password never generates the same hash twice. Letting PHP generate the salt just ensures it's relatively unpredictable and unique per hashed password, which is all it needs. You really need to read up on the basics of password security, hashing algorithms and salts - this has nothing to do with PHP's API which just simplifies it all to the core you need.

Comment: i will read up on it however could you just explain: Which string do you use in password_verify($password, $this->hash); and what is $this->hash ?

Comment: `$this->hash` is just how you could/would store it in a `User` class, and is the hash string you've stored in your database. Please, this is really all explained [extremely well on the PHP site](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

Answer (score 1):

`About` Encryption key:

**Best** Encrуption kеy is a binary blob that's gеnеrated from a rеliablе **random numbеr** gеnеrator. Thе following еxample would bе rеcommеndеd (>= 5.3):

```
$keySize = mcrypt_get_key_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB);
$encryptionKey = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($key_size, $strong); //$strong will be true if the key is crypto safe
```

But in your case you just set the string, use some random data for this.

Comment: Actually the OP is talking about a salt, not an encryption key. The salt for BCrypt should have 22 characters and must fullfill certain conditions (only characters of a given alphabet). It's best to let `password_hash()` generate its own salt.